# Querying a mixed type column in Amazon Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I have an Athena table that has a column in it that I would like to query. The type of the column is double, but it contains data of mixed types. The data is either:

- A double (0-1 inclusive)
- An array with 0 or 1 elements (again, a double 0-1 inclusive).

I have no idea how the column go into this state. I'm just trying to fix it.

If I do a naive query:

```
SELECT col FROM tbl.db;
```

I get the error: "HIVE_BAD_DATA: Error parsing field value '[]' for field 0: org.openx.data.jsonserde.json.JSONArray cannot be cast to java.lang.Double"

Some things that I've tried, but don't work:

###### Use try_cast

The docs on try_cast make it sound like the perfect solution; reality is not so kind.

When I tried to run

```
SELECT COALESCE(
    try_cast(col AS double),
    try_cast(col AS array<double>)) FROM tbl.db;
```

I get the error: "SYNTAX_ERROR: line 3:5: Cannot cast double to array(double)". Indeed, when I try more simple examples, I continue to get an error: both

```
SELECT try_cast(3.4 AS array<double>);

SELECT try_cast(ARRAY [3.4] AS double);
```

trigger errors. It appears that, although the docs claim that a cast error would cause the function to return `null`, perhaps that only works when casting between primitive data types.

###### Cast to JSON

While casting both doubles and arrays to JSON works fine as in these examples:

```
SELECT try_cast(3.4 AS JSON);

SELECT try_cast(ARRAY [3.4] AS JSON);
```

when I perform the cast on the actual column like so:

```
SELECT try_cast(col AS JSON) FROM tbl.db;
```

I get the error: "HIVE_BAD_DATA: Error parsing field value '["0.01"]' for field 0: org.openx.data.jsonserde.json.JSONArray cannot be cast to java.lang.Double"

I'd really like to be able to query this data. Alternatively, if it's possible to migrate it into a state where it's all one type, that would be an acceptable solution as well.

Comment: Do you have a reference to some documentation that says Athena allows a "mixed-type column"?

Comment: I don't. I haven't really been able to find much documentation that addresses this problem.

I just have access to an instance that exhibits this behavior.

Comment: I suspect that Amazon Athena requires every row in the table to have the same type for each column.

Comment: There is no such thing as mixed types in Presto. You need to change the column type to json or varchar. How/where do you set up it? You need to fix this mapping, there is nothing you can do when you query the data.